# Alternating series convergence with log

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

> **Question 3**. The numerical series
>
> $$\sum^\infty_{n=1}(-1)^n\left(e^{1/(n+1)^5}-1\right)\log n$$
>
> (A) converges but not absolutely
> (B) is indeterminate
> (C) positively diverges
> (D) converges absolutely

I’ve been looking at this a while and I’m not really sure how to do this. I tried the leibniz test, but it’s not exactly trivial to show that this is monotone decreasing. So I moved on to looking for absolute convergence, however I can’t really think of a test that’d work for this except for comparison test. However I don’t really see a good candidate. Maybe $\ln{x}<x$ could be useful.

Comment: You can use Taylor's theorem to show that $$
e^x  - 1 \le xe
$$ for $0<x<1$. Can you use this to prove absolute convergence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Consider absolute value and then use $e^{1/(n+1)^5}-1 \sim \frac{1}{(n+1)^5}, n\to \infty$.

Comment: Critics are invited to a friendly discussion, especially when hint is in correct direction.

Comment: Is this a trivial equivalence? I sort of fail to see it. If it is taken at face value I guess this is indeed absolutely convergent due to the asymptotic comparison test

Comment: @Learath2 Do you know $$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{{e^x  - 1}}{x} = 1?
$$ Just look at the power series of $e^x$.

Comment: @Learath2. May be It can be called "trivial": one way is in Gary's comment, but it can be done without power series, simply based on $e$ definition.  And yes, your guess about absolute convergence is correct. Do you need proof of equivalence?

Comment: Hm, as x tends to 0 I can see this working out, but we are taking n all the way to infinity. Is the radius of convergence for this power series infinite?

Comment: For $e^x$ radius of convergence is infinite, but you do not need it. We have $e^{1/(n+1)^5}$, so, when $n$ tends to infinity, then power tends to zero. This is enough to estimate remainder of series and so make conclusion about convergence.